# Rails Bootstrap broke Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

Im building a rails news app, Im using Devise for authentication. - I just installed twitter bootstrap - (twbs/bootstrrap-sass) Now when I try and login in or create a new user nothing happens. Here is a copy of my log. Any suggestions?

```
    Started GET "/users/sign_in?
utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=aVBlvsx4myc%2BP91qvVF4OENxrq5RMMtXqZyZD%2Bk3USROHJxoQ5LHfiuRwUGKzypB178miOD5pcrUpXOwkDeAYg%3D%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=david%40email.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bremember_me%5D=0&commit=Log+in" for 10.240.1.18 at 2017-07-19 11:56:18 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.240.1.18! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aVBlvsx4myc+P91qvVF4OENxrq5RMMtXqZyZD+k3USROHJxoQ5LHfiuRwUGKzypB178miOD5pcrUpXOwkDeAYg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"david@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
  Rendered partials/_jumbotron.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 325ms (Views: 74.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here is my application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Newsroom
    class Application < Rails::Application
[x] config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '10.240.1.18"

    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    end
  end
end
```

Here is a log for a different app that is working:

```
Started GET "/" for 10.240.1.4 at 2017-07-19 12:35:47 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.240.1.4! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by SiteController#home as HTML
  Rendering site/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered site/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 28.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

for some reason when I try and sign up on my new app its not running any sql

Answer (score 0):

you need to whitelist that ip in application.rb or in config/environments/development.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = "10.240.1.18"
end
```

this document might help
https://github.com/rails/web-console#configweb_consolewhitelisted_ips

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much. emm it doesn't seem to like that, it isn't reading the 'end'

Comment: you answer got cut off, did it work, what is emm, what is the new error?

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I'm not sure what happened. I am getting 'unterminated string meets end of file - syntax error, unexpected end of imput, expecting keyword end. Everything is right, all indented. For some reason its not reading the 'end'

Comment: your not closing off something, your maybe missing a actual 'end' keyword. of you left off a " on end of say a class or something. Usually that is easy to locate as the code will be colored differently after the spot the " is missing. Paste more code if you want me to help debug it with you.

Comment: Hey, thanks a million, I pasted it above. I marked the error with [x]

Comment: Thanks you so much, it is still unresponsive though.

Comment: you restarted the server, after that whats the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, when i enter username and pasword or whn i sign up as a new user and pres sign up nothing happens. The log is the same as above. I will include an example of a log for a different app that is working above.

Comment: how did you install bootstrap? gem, files or cdn?

Comment: i used the gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6 and then took content from the bootstrap example 'jumbotron'. I created a partials folder in views and put the jumbotron in a _jumbotron.html.erb file. Then I rendered that to my index page and used a condition to only render it to my index page

Comment: sorry for no replay, was trying to replicate the error

Comment: im going on a flyer, here cause very confused after looking, only thing is i saw issues with turbolinks in past? remove turbolinks and see if that works, if not im sorry and hope you solve it. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/396